summary() function not working in cnn (ValueError: Undefined shapes are not supported.)
I'm trying to make a classification network for IDing pictures from the cifar10 dataset.
When I try to use the summary() function, I keep getting this error.
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[267], line 4
      1 #base_model.summary()
      2 #top_model.summary()
      3 #print(base_model.output_shape)
----> 4 model2.summary()

File c:\Users\noahc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\noahc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\optree\ops.py:747, in tree_map(func, tree, is_leaf, none_is_leaf, namespace, *rests)
    745 leaves, treespec = _C.flatten(tree, is_leaf, none_is_leaf, namespace)
    746 flat_args = [leaves] + [treespec.flatten_up_to(r) for r in rests]
--> 747 return treespec.unflatten(map(func, *flat_args))

ValueError: Undefined shapes are not supported.

Here's the code...
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.applications import VGG16

base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))

top_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Flatten(input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:]),
    layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

for layer in base_model.layers[:10]:
    layer.trainable = False

model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    base_model,
    top_model
])

model2.summary() # Error Occurs Here

I've done a summary for the base and top model and it works fine. But when I test model2 the error occurs. Have no idea why. Not sure what it means by 'undefined' shapes. Not sure what else to try. The summary worked when I only took the first 11 or 15 layers of the vgg16. I've heard it might be a problem with the python version itself, but idk...

It is never a good idea to mix Keras with tf.keras

Since it is so, please post a self-answer.

I just removed input_shape=base_model.output_shape[1:] and it worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
